# Stuck at debugging with message "Waiting for Debugger" in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I try to use Android Studio's Debug function, the Run status would always stuck at:

Launching application: No local changes, not deploying APK

```
$ adb shell am start -D -n "com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb/com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb.activities.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb.test | com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb.test | com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb.test | com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb.test | com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb.test | com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb.test | com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb.test | com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb
Waiting for application to come online:
```

So the question is what can I do to make Android Studio debugging work?

Comment: Are you on Android Studio and using Instant Run?

Answer (score 3):

Try to Restart/Reboot your Device. It's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to kill the debugger an re-attach it while process is running -

1. **Run | Stop** -> kill the debugger
2. **Run | Attach debugger to android process** (last option in the menu) **| choose your app's process.**  -> re-attaches your debugger to your app process while it's alive.

Comment: There is no **Stop** option

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky If you're running the app in debugging mode. Tap on 'Run' -> 'Stop Android Debugger'. Anther way from the debugging panel, there's a red square to terminate the debugging session.

Answer (score 0):

remove -D from your command:

```
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb/com.example.nagamacmini.retrofitomdb.activities.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove your debuggeable device or close emulator and reconnect it or relaunch it. It will work.